# MVVM Light with ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, light

I'm a big fan of MVVM Light and I use it in my WPF Application.
It works Greeeeat.

I have a new project in asp.net mvc. And I'm wondering : Is anyone already tried to use mvvm light and asp.net mvc ?

I know that some components will obviously not work but maybe, someone has achieved to do a better job with it.

Thanks for your feedback :)

Hasan

Answer (score 2):

MVVM Light is for WPF and Silverlight, it has nothing to do with ASP.NET... so no, you can't use it for ASP.NET MVC. It would be like trying to use a saw to drive a nail ;)

Comment: I think, he thinking about a startup project, or project template for MVC that implements most of the neccesary techniques, references for a good MVC application, like IoC, MockUp, Services, templates, lots of common usable helpers.
I also search for that, or if Ihave enough time, make it.